# Is it possible to upgrade Canon 1100D screen to one with better resolution?

Tags: canon, focus, resolution, upgrade

While the question as per title can naturally be answered with "Just get a better camera", I still would like to know for the following reason: my 1100D still has some life in it and because I'm just a hobbyist I cannot really justify spending X amount for a new camera while this one works fine for me in the majority of situations I am shooting at.

The real issue I am encountering with the current display is that because of its low resolution I cannot trust it to double-check if I've got my subject in focus. I've tried with different screen brightness settings, I've tried zooming in and out, but still sometimes the picture appears perfectly fine up until I import it on my laptop only to see that it has missed focus.

Comment: I've never found a camera yet that gives you the ability to judge sharp focus on the back of the camera as well as you can when pixel peeping with a medium to large size computer monitor.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a cost-effective upgrade even if it can be done: obscure specialist skilled job with non standard part will likely be relatively expensive. You may find calibrating your lenses will help with focus issues.

Comment: The 1100D does not give the end user AFMA ability.

Comment: Though I've not used them there are remote tools that *might* provide live view through a phone or tablet, e.g. https://iluvphotography.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/get-your-remote-application-for-canon-1100d/, https://www.tethertools.com/camera/canon-1100d/

Comment: Can  you post an example image? Are you using a tripod? What other equipment are you using besides the 1100D? There are combinations of equipment and subject and scene that may favor one technique over another. For example shooting a close focus subject at slow speed with a wide aperture while hand held. It could also possibly be an issue with a particular lens...though technique is more likely.

Answer (score 2):

You could try attaching an external "field monitor" to your camera. (Probably not cheap, though.) These are small LCD screens you can buy, some of which can bolt into the flash shoe on the top of the camera. From there, you just hook the camera's HDMI output into the monitor with a short cable. Many of them even have a little sun shade, so you can actually see the screen properly.

Alternatively, transfer the pictures to your phone via Wi-Fi (if your camera body has that feature... I'm guessing it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

You could go another Way and lover your aparture to 5.6 or 8, measure your distance to the object using an app on your smartphone or use a measure laser device, and go on manual focus, and adjust the focus ring on your camera to the measured distance, this might do the trick, even though it is a bit more cumbersome :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's not possible to upgrade the builtin display, so the only option is to use an external display.

The 1000D does not have an HDMI interface, just an analogue video out, which supports PAL and NTSC video. I'm not sure there are displays for this an if, what the price is.

The 1000D also has no WiFi. Sure, there are WiFi SD-cards, but from SD-cards, you can only load already taken photos.

I would suggest to use a mobile phone app which connects to the camera via USB. The phone needs to support USB OTG which means it is not only a "device" being connected to a "computer", but can act itself as "computer" where "devices" can be connected. Most modern android mobiles support this for Apple, I don't know.

An app can not only download already shot photos, it can also act as life view display with its full resolution including magnification, and as trigger. It is also possbilbe to set the focus and all the other usual settings, and even more. For example, the camera itself allows to take three photos with different settings for HDR photos, while an app can take... well, as many as you want.

On the other side, a mobile phone attached to the camera via cable is not practical, and you need a tripod. But an external monitor isn't much better.

---

Finally, it would be interesting to know why your photos are unsharp. I own a 700D and in automatic mode I used the first days, the camera guessed what to put in focus, and was wrong more often than right. So, how do you take your photos? (Maybe, you have an example?)